# selecting all DIV which have style display none

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I am using prototype framework to select all the DIV which have style `display:none`

I am using

```
$$(".details-wrapper > div[style*=display:'none']")
```

or

```
$$(".details-wrapper > div[style*=display:none]")
```

but it's not working. Any suggestion?

Comment: Matching on a style attribute is almost always a bad idea - it will not match anything that was set via JavaScript or through a CSS rule. In jQuery you could simply use the `:hidden` selector.

Comment: It will match things set via JavaScript, usually, since scripts have to set it either inline or in the stylesheet.  As for things set via a stylesheet, I don't think there is a way to match those, short of scanning every element on the page (brute force) or somethin that scans the stylesheet and tries every selector that could set `display: none`.

Comment: @Brilliand–not all browsers reflect properties in attribues, so an attribute based selector may not get elements with properties set by script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$$(".details-wrapper > div[style*='display:none']");
```

The [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gVzZw/).

Comment: You might also want to try `display: none` and `display:  none` and `display :none` and... you get the drift.  Might want to just search for `display` and `none` separately, then double-check that the retrieved elements are really resolving as `display: none`.

Comment: For reference: Checking whether a single element resolves as `display:none` can be done via `currentStyle["display"]` (for old IE) and `getComputedStyle("display", null)` (for others).

Comment: Erm... that second `display: none` (in my first comment) was double-spaced.  Rare, perhaps, but legal.